# Isolated biblography entries without a biblography

Tags: bibtex, bibentry

I'm trying to create isolated biblography entries without an actual biblography, but they don't show up in the final compiled document at all.

MWE:

`document.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}
    Some text
    \bibentry{thing}
    \bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \nobibliography{biblography}
    \nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

`biblography.bib`

```
@Article{thing,
author="Someone",
title="Something",
journal="Some Journal",
year="2018",
month="Feb",
day="12",
}
```

The output is a document that only contains "Some text" but no biblography entry. I want the entry to show up.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed that. You need to issue `\nobibliography{...}` before you use any `\bibentry` commands

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Documentation was sparse on that. I could delete the question, but it's best to leave it up, so could you make that into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must issue `\nobibliography` *before* any use of `\bibentry`.

The [`bibentry` documentation](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/bibentry2.pdf) says

> These [`\bibentry`] commands may only be issued after `\nobibliography`, for otherwise the reference texts are not known.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{thing,
author="Someone",
title="Something",
journal="Some Journal",
year="2018",
month="Feb",
day="12",
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
  \nobibliography{\jobname}
  Some text
  \bibentry{thing}
  \bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```